# Using HTML input element (type="submit"), how can we customize the GET field?

Tags: html, input, get

Using `<form method="get">` element including `<input type="submit">` element, we can have a way to GET a web page with some fields specified by the `<input type="text" name="studentId">` elements, but can I customize those fields?

For example: I always want to add a `action=true` to the GET url to let the URL be something like this: `http://example.com/?studentId=123&action=true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden form field, though the name `action` is not a good one, as `form` has an `action` attribute and this name can conflict when scripting the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="something" name="something" value="somthingelse" />
```

Comment: There is no name conflict between the form action attribute and adding an input with the name action. Otherwise I would have marked the answer up for using a hidden input as an answer to the OP. Also using an id on a hidden input is not necessary.

Comment: @StuartWakefield - I have had problems with scripts failing to run when specific `input` names have corresponding names to existing `form` attributes (most commonly buttons called `submit`). Action has a similar issue when it comes to scripting.

Comment: it would be interesting to get some details. I have never had this issue. JavaScript, PHP, ColdFusion. Perhaps .NET might throw up slightly...

Comment: @StuartWakefield - I have seen this with JavaScript when accessing forms directly (using `document.forms[0].action` would be ambiguous if you also had both an `action` attribute and an `action` input.

Comment: Ahh, good call. I never use that construct I always prefer `document.getElementsByName("action")` and `form.getAttribute("action")`, but yes I can see the issue now.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="true" />`

inside your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="gbqffd">
   <input type="hidden" value="en" name="h1">
   <input type="hidden" value="d" name="tbo">
   <input type="hidden" value="search" name="output">
   <input type="hidden" value="psy-ab" name="sclient">
 </div>
```

Google always has the answer; in this case I never had to do a search just look at the source :)